# Custom EntityNotFoundDelegate

Tags: hibernate

I get a `org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException` when I want to delete an object which doesn't exist anymore via hibernate. I just want this exception to be ignored. I could catch the exception and ignore, this would be a solution maybe. But, since there is a hibernate support for ignoring this exception through `org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration#entityNotFoundDelegate`, I would like to use its advantage and control it using configuration. The question is then, how can I introduce my own/custom implementation of **`EntityNotFoundDelegate`** to the org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration? Does anybody have a sample code for me? Just an additional tip, I use Spring Framework as well in my project.

Here is the exception that I get:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateObjectRetrievalFailureException: No row with the given identifier exists: [de.mycompany.domain.ResultObject#810b1334-32d3-02b0-e044-769e0ab48e48]; nested exception is org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [de.mycompany.domain.ResultObject#810b1334-32d3-02b0-e044-769e0ab48e48]
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:660)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:412)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.delete(HibernateTemplate.java:865)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.delete(HibernateTemplate.java:859)
   at de.mycompany.utils.dao.impl.PersistentDaoImpl.delete(PersistentDaoImpl.java:50)
   at de.mycompany.utils.service.ServiceImpl.delete(ServiceImpl.java:68)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
   at de.mycompany.utils.service.ServiceInterceptor.invoke(ServiceInterceptor.java:43)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
   at $Proxy3.delete(Unknown Source)
   ... 14 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [de.mycompany.domain.ResultObject#810b1334-32d3-02b0-e044-769e0ab48e48]
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl$2.handleEntityNotFound(SessionFactoryImpl.java:409)
   at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:108)
   at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:97)
   at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:140)
   at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.unproxyAndReassociate(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:594)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:90)
   at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:74)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireDelete(SessionImpl.java:793)
   at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.delete(SessionImpl.java:778)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$26.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:871)
   at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:419)
   ... 30 more
```

And my versions:

**Hibernate: 3.3.1**

**Spring: 2.5.6**

Thanks in advance!

Felix

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure this is the intended use. Quoting the javadoc *"Specify a user-supplied delegate to be used to handle scenarios where an entity could not be located by specified id. This is mainly intended for EJB3 implementations to be able to control how proxy initialization errors should be handled..."*. For me, the real question is: why are you deleting a non existing entity?

Comment: Hi Pascal,

yeah, the java-doc comment tells the intention indeed. This EntityNotFoundDelegate is possibly a different way of implementing not-found="exception"/"ignore" attribute in <many-to-one> mapping elements.

The reason why I want to ignore a delete on not existing db-record is, that when two cliens load the same data and one deletes it. The other client wants to delete exactly the same data. This second deletion has to be ignored in our test case. Maybe it is a better idea to do it explicitly by catching the exception.

Comment: *I* would handle the exception indeed.

Answer (score 2):

If you use an explicit `Configuration`, you can call the [`setEntityNotFoundDelegate`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/Configuration.html#setEntityNotFoundDelegate%28org.hibernate.proxy.EntityNotFoundDelegate%29) method with a custom `EntityNotFoundDelegate` implementation that overrides `handleEntityNotFound` to do nothing.

Using Spring, this is implemented by specifying a custom `SessionFactory`. For example, you can extend `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and override `buildSessionFactory` to call `sfb.setEntityNotFoundDelegate` before building the session factory.

```
public class LocalSessionFactoryBeanIgnoringErrors extends LocalSessionFactoryBean {

    @Override
    protected SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder sfb) {
        sfb.setEntityNotFoundDelegate(new EntityNotFoundDelegate() {

            @Override
            public void handleEntityNotFound(String entityName, Serializable id) {
                System.out.println("Entity " + entityName + " with id " + id + " not found");
            }
        });
        return sfb.buildSessionFactory();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you expand about this ?  I need to improve the handleEntityNotFound so i can get the Entity name and the Id ,but not inside a String